# Implementing fixed precision numbers in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to speed up my code by using fixed precision numbers in CUDA. I need 64 bit.  How can I do the multiply without overflowing and clipping off the top of my numbers.  Is there a 128 bit type in CUDA.

```
typedef long long fixed;
#define _fxadd(a, b) ((a) + (b))
#define _fxsub(a, b) ((a) - (b))
#define _fxmul(a, b) ((a) * (b)) >> 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in 128-bit wide integer data type in CUDA, but there are some [integer intrinsics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT), that may help with your own implementation.

For instance, you might use `__umul64hi` to obtain higher limb of multiplication by 64-bits wide (unsigned) integer operands:

> Calculate the most significant 64 bits of the 128-bit product x * y,
>   where x and y are 64-bit unsigned integers.